# Encouraging people to vote

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

Low vote count could be remedied with making Supporter and Critic badges capable of being awarded multiple times. Like one badge per 10 votes. What do you think?

Comment: Watch the downvotes rise vertiginously. Can you explain why you think answers need to have more upvotes. Imagine if ten users upvoted the same answer because they all wanted a new shiny badge, wouldn't that invalidate the answer?

Comment: I think this type of request has been made several times....

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89008/should-there-be-more-incentive-to-upvote and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions?rq=1 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/why-are-votes-per-post-on-the-decrease-what-can-we-do-to-improve-this?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84115/get-points-for-voting

Comment: I cannot find a question which specifically requests awarding a badge for upvoting, in the meantime here is another Q: [What is our reward for voting? What is the metric for voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29615/what-is-our-reward-for-voting-what-is-the-metric-for-voting?rq=1)

Comment: What benefit are we supposed to receive from encouraging more voting?

Comment: The reputation what else

Answer (score 11):

I think we already have other badges for this purpose, which work sufficiently well:

- The bronze [Suffrage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/118/suffrage) badge:

  > Use 30 votes in a day.
- The bronze [Vox Populi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/147/vox-populi) badge:

  > Use the maximum 40 votes in a day.
- The silver [Civic Duty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) badge:

  > Vote 300 or more times.
- The gold [Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate) badge:

  > Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions.

Comment: Well, 30 - 40 votes **in one day** sounds like early Soviet Union with its "300% of norm". Perhaps the number shouldn't  be counted per day. Like a badge **every** 30 - 40 votes?

Answer (score 3):

> Low vote count could be remedied

Stop right there. "Low vote count" is not something that needs to be "remedied".

There are good posts, and there are bad posts. But most posts are just... meh. They're OK. They're not great, they aren't anything terrific that makes you really think or otherwise tells you something of significance. But they're not bad. They're just meh.

Encouraging people to vote on *anything*, to sort every post into two boxes, is a terrible thing for the site. It misrepresents the nature of content on the site by forcing everyone to classify everything as either being good or bad. Some posts are better than others, and voting needs to recognize that. And it can't do that if a mid-quality post gets upvoted as highly as a high-quality post.

Not voting is a *good thing*. There is no problem that needs to be fixed.